# Generic method to check consistency of initial conditions for PDE system

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a generic way to check for the consistency of IC in PDE systems?

I have the following code, but I get an `NDSolveValue::icfail` error:

```
$Assumptions = 
  Exp[\[Lambda][t, r]] > 0 && Exp[-\[Lambda][t, r]] > 0 && R[t, r] > 0;

c = 1;
l0 = -1;
r0 = 1;
\[Nu][t_, r_] := 1/4 Log[1/\[Epsilon][t, r]];
\[Epsilon][t_, r_] := (
  100 (r^2 Exp[l0])^(4/3))/(R[t, r]^2 Exp[\[Lambda][t, r]])^(4/3);
m[t_, r_] := 
  1/2 R[t, r] (1 - D[R[t, r], r]^2 Exp[-2 \[Lambda][t, r]] + 
     D[R[t, r], t]^2 Exp[-2 \[Nu][t, r]]);

eq1 = D[R[t, r], t, r] == 
   Simplify[
    D[R[t, r], t] D[\[Nu][t, r], r] + 
     D[R[t, r], r] D[\[Lambda][t, r], t]];
eq2 = FullSimplify[
    Exp[-2 \[Nu][t, r]] (D[R[t, r], {t, 2}] - 
        D[\[Nu][t, r], t] D[R[t, r], t]) - 
     Exp[-2 \[Lambda][t, r]] D[\[Nu][t, r], r] D[R[t, r], r] + 
     m[t, r]/R[t, r]^2 + 4 Pi \[Epsilon][t, r] R[t, r]] == 0;

ic = {R[0, r] == r, 
   Derivative[1, 0][R][0, r] == c, \[Lambda][0, r] == l0};
bc = {R[t, 1] == 1 + c t, \[Lambda][t, 1] == l0};
NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, ic, bc}, {R, \[Lambda]}, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 1, 10}, Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA",  "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton",  "LinearSolveMethod" -> "Direct"}}}]
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following:

1. Assume `R[0,r]==r`, `Derivative[1,0][R][0,r]==c`, `l0==f[r]`.
2. Substitute into `eq1` and `eq2`
3. Solve for `c` and `f[r]` with `t==0`

I have found that `c` can be anything and that

```
f[r]==1/2 (Log[3/(3 - 10 c^2 + 2400 \[Pi] r^2)])
```

4. I have used the above into my `NDSolveValues` but I still get the same `NDSolveValue::icfail` error